# WordPress WP_Query - Can't query post_title

Tags: sql, wordpress

I can't get the following code to pass a LIKE parameter a return just the posts starting with "jazz".

```
    <?php 
$artist_post_title = 'jazz'
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'post_title' => '%' . $artist_post_title
);

?>

<?php $user_query = new WP_Query( $args); ?> 

<?php if( $user_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $user_query->have_posts() ) : $user_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was intrigued by your question, and did some digging myself.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something

Basically, by defining a filter for WP_Query you can create a precise result set.

Comment: Thanks for looking and I found that article too.  I just figured it couldn't require that much work to do something I can do in real SQL in about a minute.

I can't believe this is so difficult.  I have to create a function to call a field.  I can call the name (slug) field without an issue, but the actual post title requires an act of congress. 

At least it good to know I'm the only person ever that might need to search by post title...

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one.. Sometime, Wordpress sucks.